# iOS Quartz 2D Graphics Filled Irregular Shapes Blurry

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-graphics

I'm drawing irregular shapes using Core Graphics on a retina display. I do this by creating a UIBezierPath with 5 to 10 random points. In drawRect I stroke the path and fill it using solid red colour.

My problem is that diagonal lines in my drawing doesn't appear to be sharp.

I have tried anti aliasing but if anything this makes it appear worse. I have experimented with different line widths, not stroking, not filling, but I can not seem to get a really sharp diagonal line.

For comparison I created a similar shape in Photoshop (using similar size) and saved that as PNG. If I display that PNG on iOS it looks much sharper.

What can I do to make my shape that I create in code look sharp?

Comment: Post your drawing code, maybe it can give better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `CGPoint`'s are rounded to the nearest integer value.